# Looking for the name of a show about a saxophone player super hero

Tags: story-identification, tv, super-hero

I remember a long time ago a tv series about a group of people that got super-powers from a meteorite that fell onto the earth and broke into fragments.  The main character got the ability to see a few moments into the future.  He was a sax player, and was always in a bar.  I think the bartender or owner was his sidekick, and he would go out and "fight crime" using his lame power.

It was really, really lame, but not being able to remember it is driving me crazy.

Comment: I vote we make this terrible show a running gag here on SFF. Thanks @Ben Collins. :)

Comment: The guy's a friggin' genius! MACGRUBER!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

http://youtu.be/i5LhB2X0cuA

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_Man

> Night Man is an American action/adventure/sci-fi series that aired in syndication from 15 September, 1997 to 17 May, 1999. The series is loosely based on a comic book published by Malibu Comics and was created by Steve Englehart (the original comic title was The Night Man) and developed for television by Glen A. Larson.
>
> It stars Matt McColm as the title character, a superhero whose real name was Johnny Domino, a saxophonist. Englehart would write three episodes of the series. Nightman is also one of the few series to cross over with characters from Larson's previous series: in the episode "Manimal", Johnny allies with Professor Jonathan Chase, the star of the short-lived 1980s' series Manimal. The show aired nationally on WGN Superstation from its premiere through 2005.

I vaugely remember this terrible terrible show. Terrible.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, I also see that it made #1 on this list of worst shows ever.  http://www.forevergeek.com/2007/07/top_10_worst_sci-fi_shows_ever_wvideos/  Truly, truly terrible.

Comment: Actually it was Valiant Comics he first appeared in but later i guess marvel/malibu took it over

Comment: @user4699:
Shadowman was a Jazz-playing voodoo Valiant superhero created by Englehart, but they are not the same person.