# looking for a sci fi cartoon (american) from late 80s early 90s

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon, warfare

For years I remember a TV show that I didn't like, and would only watch the opening credits. I remember it from primary school so it must have been on TV between 1989-1992 at least-
it featured some sort of planet or futuristic world, where the enemies were machines, I remember a shot where there were soldier or tanks on a rocky outcrop and this machine, or tank or something was being hatched out, they seemed to be hatched out of weird globs- almost like a grape being squeezed out of its skin.
I know it had a line of toys and was somewhat popular because all the boys at school always wanted to play.
I would love if anyone could identify this TV show for me!
I'm very sure it was American, although it played here in New Zealand.

Answer (score 7):

This sounds very much like [*Jayce and the Wheeled Warriors*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jayce_and_the_Wheeled_Warriors) to me (broadcast on Nickelodeon from 1989-1991). The villains are these plant-based, transformer-like vehicles that would drive around through space on giant vines. Check out [this YouTube video of the shows intro](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A1c1G24GWDg) and see if it rings any bells. There's also [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pXl_wX9hJkc) of one of the commercials for the Mattel toy line.

Comment: I was actually thinking about asking this but all I could remember were the vines through space

Comment: This looks even worse than [Night Man](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2869/looking-for-the-name-of-a-show-about-a-saxophone-player-super-hero).